# How to create a depth-recording shader for shadow mapping?

Tags: shaders, fragment-shader, shadows, shadow-mapping

I am attempting to implement shadow maps.

I am first going to implement spotlights over directional lights (I am aware this is harder).

Since I was already rendering the geometry, my attempt was to recycle my old shaders and modify them to make shaders to create the depth maps.

This created the following vertex shader:

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position; //(x,y,z) coordinates of a vertex

layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer data_buffer
{
    vec4 cubes_info[];//first 3 values are position of object 
};

uniform mat4 view = mat4(1); //Camera orientation and position
uniform mat4 proj = mat4(1); //The projection parameters (FOV, viewport dimensions)

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj*view*(vec4(position, 1.0) + vec4(vec3(cubes_info[gl_InstanceID]),0));
}
```

And fragment shader:

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) out float fragmentdepth;

void main()
{
    fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

As you can see, both shaders are pretty basic, they are a little more complex than they would otherwise be since they are using instancing, but overall they are simple.

However the output of these shaders is:

[image: Screenshot of voxel terrain, in full 0xFF0000 red]

Where the original image is:

[image: Screenshot of grey-white voxel terrain, with lihting applied]

As you can see, the depth is being lost.

I think this is because my perspective, projection and model matrices are identical for both shaders.

In other words, I think that the camera I use for rendering the second image does not store the depth information. I wanted to know how can you generate a similar projection matrix to store the depth?

Comment: If your normal camera/projection transformations weren't passing depth through properly, how is it that your second image appears to be correctly z-buffered, with no places where a faraway cube draws over a nearby one due to identical depth results from the matrix? To me, this looks like your matrix is probably fine, and you might just need to tune how you're reading & remapping the depth value from the transformed result.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you need to understand that the red component is actually visually correct.  The Z Depth is being embedded in values close to 1.

If you want to just see a colour change to see the depth values more visually, you can either shorten the back plane to allow a greater range of values (not tracking close 1.0f).

I usually use the trick of depth = saturate((depth - 0.95f) * 20.0f);

What this does is stretch that part of the z buffer out (when im replaying the buffer back through a Pixel shader).

You may find what you have is working perfectly fine.  Z Depth is not written in a linear fashion btw most of the time.

Sample of what you should see in your shadow buffer

[image: Shadow buffer content vs backbuffer]

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, the values are not "close" to 1, they are all exactly 1.

Dividing by any scalar just results in a different shade of grey, not a variation in color as you would expect from a depth map.

Comment: refer to the additional picture

Comment: @Makogan You're under the assumption that gl_FragCoord.z is linear. It's not.

https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/76ae79